# How get data of single user's in own_reactions using stream_python?

Tags: getstream-io

In order to fetch a feed using stream_client the documentation says.

```
feed = stream_client.feed('feed_group', 'some valid id')
feed_data = feed.get(enrich=True, reactions = {'own':True})
```

In this case, own_reactions contains data of more than one users.

How can I filter the own_reactions by only one user while fetching the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shuould specify `user_id` when doing `feed.get` like so:

```
feed_data = feed.get(enrich=True, reactions={'own': True}, user_id='jelte')
```

This is also shown in the docs here: https://getstream.io/docs/python/#reactions_read-feeds